# How can I print class content?

Tags: ruby

I have a newbie question!
I want to do something like this:

```
puts Example.new([a,b,c])
```

and the result to be

```
=> a,b,c
```

I tried something like this:

```
class Example
  attr_accessor :something
  def initialize(something)
  @something = something
  puts @something
  end
end
```

It works but not how I want it!
Thank you!

Comment: .. but not how I want it .. do you mean, you want the variable names printed instead of their values?

Comment: no. I want the variables printed but by doing directly "puts Example.new(variable1, variable2, variable3).
I want something like this but I don't know how to do it:

class Example
attr_accessor :something
def initialize(something)
@something = something
end
def something_else
@something = @something.to_s + "x"
end
end

puts Example.new(something)

and this thing to return "somethingx"

Comment: Why would you want to do this though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would something like this work ?

```
class Example
  def initialize(args = [])
    @args = args
  end

  def to_s
    @args.join(",")
  end
end

puts Example.new([1,2,3])
>> 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking to print (in readable form) an object?  Try using the [inspect method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000360).

```
class Myobj
  attr_accessor :x, :y, :z
end

a = Myobj.new
a.x = 1; a.y = 2; a.z = 3
a.inspect  #=> "#<Myobj:0x1bc48950 @y=2, @x=1, @z=3>"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I don't want to write a = Myobj.new. I want do directly puts Myobj.new(x,y,z) and to get printed x, y, z Thank you